# WebSphere Memory Leak after restarting the application

Tags: java, jsf, memory-leaks, websphere

I am analyzing the Head Dump of my WAS 8.5 using Eclipse MAT.

I have extracted in the beginning a very large Head Dump, around 700 MB, and I have found that there's lots of duplicate entries for `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl` (see image below).

[image]

The main object that can be found under it is a class in my JSF application called `DataUtils`, this class is an Application Scoped Bean with eager equals to true, it runs when starting the application in order to load some data and store them in the memory.

[image]

I suppose that the the size taken by this bean shouldn't be a problem, however it is the duplicated objects that are causing this huge memory.

Now in order to identify why I'm having these duplicated objects, I rebooted the server, then started WAS and the application, I took the Head Dump and analyzed it, all was good, with a very small size 50 MB. (I know by now that `DataUtils` was already initialized and the data were loaded)

Then I stopped the application, and then started it again, knowing that `DataUtils` is going to be initialized, I took a Head Dump and found the first duplicated `WebAppImpl` object.

[image]

You can also notice marked in red, the `DataUtils` class is duplicated.

After a 2nd stop-start, the duplication increases.

[image]

I'm not sure if I provided enough information and even if my assumption (about `DataUtils`) is correct. However is it known that Application Scoped beans are not destroyed from the memory? What else could be causing the problem?

Thanks.

**More Info**

There is one another application installed.

`DataUtils` is an Application Scoped Bean. It injects some other Beans (they are Spring beans as the same time).

```
@ManagedBean(name = "dataUtils", eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataUtils implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceFactoryExternal}")
    private ServiceFactoryExternal serviceFactoryExternal;
    public ServiceFactoryExternal getServiceFactoryExternal() {return serviceFactoryExternal;}
    public void setServiceFactoryExternal(ServiceFactoryExternal serviceFactoryExternal) {
        this.serviceFactoryExternal = serviceFactoryExternal;}

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceFactoryOperational}")
    private ServiceFactoryOperational serviceFactoryOperational;
    public ServiceFactoryOperational getServiceFactoryOperational() {return serviceFactoryOperational;}
    public void setServiceFactoryOperational(ServiceFactoryOperational serviceFactoryOperational) {
        this.serviceFactoryOperational = serviceFactoryOperational;}

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceFactoryHistorical}")
    private ServiceFactoryHistorical serviceFactoryHistorical;
    public ServiceFactoryHistorical getServiceFactoryHistorical() {return serviceFactoryHistorical;}
    public void setServiceFactoryHistorical(ServiceFactoryHistorical serviceFactoryHistorical) {
        this.serviceFactoryHistorical = serviceFactoryHistorical;}

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceFactoryLDAP}")
    private ServiceFactoryLDAP serviceFactoryLDAP;
    public ServiceFactoryLDAP getServiceFactoryLDAP() { return serviceFactoryLDAP; }
    public void setServiceFactoryLDAP(ServiceFactoryLDAP serviceFactoryLDAP) { this.serviceFactoryLDAP = serviceFactoryLDAP; }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listCountriesEnglish = serviceFactoryOperational.getCountryService().findAll("EN");
        listCountriesFrench = serviceFactoryOperational.getCountryService().findAll("FR");
        listBanks = serviceFactoryOperational.getBankService().findAll();
        listBranches = serviceFactoryOperational.getBankService().findAllBankBankBranches();
        listJudStatusEnglish = serviceFactoryOperational.getJudStatusService().findAll("EN");
        listJudStatusFrench = serviceFactoryOperational.getJudStatusService().findAll("FR");
        listCreditPortfolioEnglish = serviceFactoryOperational.getCreditPortfolioService().findAll("EN");

//Filling lists from database....

    }
    // List of Beans
    private static List<CountryBean> listCountriesEnglish;
    private static List<CountryBean> listCountriesFrench;
    private static List<Bank> listBanks;
    private static List<BankBranchesBean> listBranches;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.JudStatusBean> listJudStatusEnglish;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.JudStatusBean> listJudStatusFrench;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.CreditPortfolioBean> listCreditPortfolioEnglish;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.CreditPortfolioBean> listCreditPortfolioFrench;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.ClientClassBean> listClientClassEnglish;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.ClientClassBean> listClientClassfrench;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.RegistrationCommerce> listRegCommEnglish;
    private static List<odatabase.service.beans.RegistrationCommerce> listRegCommFrench;
    private static List<LegalFormBean> listLegalFormPPEnglish;
    private static List<LegalFormBean> listLegalFormMPEnglish;
    private static List<LegalFormBean> listLegalFormPPFrench;
    private static List<LegalFormBean> listLegalFormMPFrench;

    private static List<FamStatusBean> listFamStatusEnglish;
    private static List<FamStatusBean> listFamStatusFrench;
    private static List<MohafazaBean> listMohafazaEnglish;
    private static List<MohafazaBean> listMohafazaFrench;
    private static List<KadaaBean> listKadaaEnglish;
    private static List<KadaaBean> listKadaaFrench;
    //Other Lists...

//Other simple private methods..
}
```

One of the injected Spring Beans:

```
@ManagedBean(name="serviceFactoryExternal", eager=true)
@Component
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceFactoryExternal {

    @Autowired
    private  BcrClientService clientService;
    public void setClientService(BcrClientService clientService) { this.clientService = clientService; }
    public  BcrClientService getClientService() { return this.clientService; }

//Other Injected Spring Beans, no post construct.
}
```

Comment: How many webapps do you have? any chance to see the class DataUtils?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto please check my answer added above.

Comment: Check this out [Memory leaks in Java Platform, Enterprise Edition applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ctrb_memleakdetection.html). Your bean contains static variables. Since it is already application scoped, there should be one instance. So try to remove theses `statics` from all variables.